# The probability of taking one specific value is zero in normal distribution, but then the probability in a range of values is not zero?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

In the normal distribution, the probability of taking one specific value is said to be zero (because there are an infinite number of values, so the probability of one specific value is infinitesimally small).

But then how can the probability of taking any value in a given range not equal zero? If all these values have probability=0 of being selected?

Comment: Why would the fact that $P(X = x) = 0$ for any $x \in \mathbb R$ imply that $P(a \leq X \leq b) = 0$? That doesn't follow.

Answer (score 2):

The term under which you can learn more about this is [countable additivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma_additivity). A probability measure is required to be countably additive, that is, the probability of the union of any countable family (that is, sequence) of pairwise disjoint events must be the sum of the individual probabilities. You’re forming the union of uncountably many events, and there’s no such requirement in that case.

A possible source of your sense of contradiction may be that you mistake “probability $0$” for “impossible”. An event can have probability $0$ and yet be possible. In fact, in case of a continuous distribution, all elementary events have probability $0$, and yet the probability that one of them will happen is $1$.

Comment: Could you further explain how probability '0' is not 'impossible'? To try and answer my own question, I just assumed that the probability of a certain number occurring tended to zero but was never zero, and the sum of these certain numbers created a probability not equal to zero.

Comment: @XXb8: That's not quite right, but it can be made rigorous like this: If you have a sequence $I_n$ of nested intervals whose intersection contains only one point, then probability that the random variable takes a value in those intervals goes to zero as the length of the intervals goes to zero, but it's never zero for any of the intervals at any finite point in the sequence. As for probability $0$ not being impossible: Remember that these are all mathematical idealizations.

Comment: @XXb8: In pratice we never have an exact real number; it makes no sense to ask whether the rainfall tomorrow will be exactly $\pi$ mm; so in practice we're effectively always dealing with intervals and not with events whose probability in the mathematical abstraction of the real numbers is zero.

Comment: @XXb8: A good example of an event with probability $0$ that doesn't come from a distribution over the real numbers is the event that you keep throwing a coin and it always shows heads, forever. This is possible, but you can't assign any non-zero probability to it, since all outcomes are equally likely and there are (uncountably) infinitely many of them, so if you assigned non-zero probability to this one the sum over countably many of them couldn't be $1$. You can link the two cases (coins and real numbers) by thinking of real numbers in terms of their binary representations.